# Necessary and sufficient condition for $f(q^n)$ to be in $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$ when $f\in\mathbb{Q}(q)[x]$?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, q-analogs

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92772/representing-the-q-binomial-coefficient-as-a-polynomial-with-coefficients-in), user begins shows that, for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a unique polynomial $P_k(x)$ of degree $k$ whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{Q}(q)$, the field of rational functions, such that $P_k(q^n)=\binom{n}{k}_q$ for all $n$.

I've read a bit more about this subject and want to ask this follow up. Suppose $f\in\mathbb{Q}(q)[x]$. Why is it true that $f(q^n)\in\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$ for all $n$ if and only if the coefficients of $f$ w.r.t. the basis $\{P_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}[q,q^{-1}]$? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the proof that a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$ takes integers to integers iff it is a linear combination withinteger coefficients of the polynomials $\binom{X}{k}$, with $k\geq0$? This should be similar...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I'm afraid not, I'll try to look into it. I was hoping to some explanation or even a sketch here.

Comment: The statement I mentioned is proved in Hartshorne's book on algebraic geometry, in Prasolov's book on Polynomials, and in many other places. I don't have thge book here to check but your question should probably be answered in Prasolov's book.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found what I wanted in there.