Rational Expressions and Simplifying
Let $m,n,r$ be positive interger numbers.
a) Prove that $$\dfrac{(x^{m+r} - 1)(x^{m+r-1}-1)\dots(x^{m+1}-1)}{(x^r-1)(x^{r-1}-1)\dots(x-1)}$$ is a polynomial.
b) Let $$a_{n,r}=\dfrac{(3^{n+r} - 1)(3^{n+r-1}-1)\dots(3^{n+1}-1)}{(3^r-1)(3^{r-1}-1)\dots(3-1)}\times3^{\dfrac{r(r+1)}{2}}, r = 1,2, \dots, m.$$Caculate $T = 1 + a_{n,1}+ a_{n,2}\dots + a_{n,m}.$
I've tried to reduce the expression in a) but I get stuck to make it simplier to caculate b). Can anybody help me?

The question a) actually asks for the Gaussian Binomial coefficients or q-binomial coefficients. They are polynomials, as for example answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92772/ . The question b) is an application of  that which uses the q-generalization of Binomial theorems.

@Andreas can you explain more to me? Because I don't know how to apply it to this problem.
